# How do I calculate $\int_0^ax^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$ via substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

I have to calculate the integral $$\int_0^ax^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$$ using solely substitution (no integration by parts). $a$ is a positive constant.

I'm confused on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=a\sin\theta\implies dx=a\cos \theta\ d\theta$
$$\int_0^a x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\ dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} a^2\sin^2\theta(a\cos\theta)(a\cos \theta\ d\theta)$$
$$=a^4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}  \sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta\ d\theta$$
$$=\frac{a^4}{4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}  (2\sin\theta\cos\theta)^2\ d\theta$$
$$=\frac{a^4}{4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^22\theta\ d\theta$$
$$=\frac{a^4}{4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1-\cos4\theta}{2}\ d\theta$$
$$=\frac{a^4}{8}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} (1-\cos4\theta)\ d\theta$$
$$=\frac{a^4}{8}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-0\right)=\frac{\pi a^4}{16}$$

Comment: Thank you, for the last step, how do you pass directly from the integral to the value?

Comment: Alright, notice you need to simply integrate & apply limits as follows $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} (1-\cos4\theta)\ d\theta=\left(\theta-\frac{\sin4\theta}{4}\right)_{0}^{\pi/2}$$ $$=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\sin2\pi}{4}-0+\frac{\sin0}{4}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Ok, I just wasn't sure if you skipped that step or if there was a more straightforward way to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Well, there *is* a (slightly) more straightforward way: $\cos 4\theta$ has period $\pi/2$, and the integral of a sine or cosine over a whole period is zero because of symmetry.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark: Yes, of course, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Use this substitution

$$x=a \sin t, \qquad 0 \le t \le \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Then your integral becomes

$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} a^4 \sin^2 t \cos^2 t dt$$

I think that you can go on now.

Comment: Thank you. I keep getting confused with the bounds, how do you get to $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}$ ?

Comment: @Gloomy: You are welcome. :) Sorry for the delay. :) I had to go. Just note that when $x=0$ then $\sin t=0$ and hence $t=0$. Similarly when $x=a$ then $\sin t =1$ and hence $t = \frac{\pi}{2}$.